# Почему сравнение строк в Java не дает true

Tags: java, android, строки, android-sdk, сравнение

Написал метод который принимает строку. Строка содержит `01` или `10`. В методе есть условие, в котором я проверяю равна, ли строка `01` или нет. Условие не проходит даже когда строка равна `01`. Вот код метода:

```
private void turn_block(String text){
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    EngineTimerTask timerTask = new EngineTimerTask();

    Log.e("magnet",text);
    if(text == "01") {
        blockFlagMagnet =true;
        mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 2000);
    }
    else v.vibrate(1000);

    mTimer = new Timer();
    byte [] value = new byte[4];
    value [0] = 0;
    value [1] = 0;
    try {
        byte [] temp = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
        value[2] = temp[0];
        value[3] = temp[1];
        mService.writeRXCharacteristic(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вибрация не останавливается, это условие `if(text == "01")` не дает `true`.
Вот подтверждение, что `01` приходит.
[image: Log-и]
В чем дело ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сравнивать строки нужно методом equals.

```
text.equals("01");
```

Строка в Java - это отдельный объект, который может не совпадать с другим объектом, хотя на экране результат выводимой строки может выглядеть одинаково. Просто Java в случае с логическим оператором == (а также !=) сравнивает ссылки на объекты (при работе с примитивами такой проблемы нет);

[Более подробное описание в конце статьи](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/string.php#equals)

Comment: Если в `text` разрешено значение `null`, то лучше сделать так - `"01".equals(text)`